# Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm running into a problem with my code. I want to edit an element's href. I need it to send open up your email when clicked with a pre-made subject and body. I'm getting the error "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" though and I'm completely not sure why.

I was hoping someone could help me with this problem.

I need to edit this attribute in javascript, so putting it in the  element to start with will not work!

There is a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7q4cq/1/).

Here is my:

HTML:

```
<a id = 'emailoff' href = "" target = "_blank">
    <div id= "btn1">
        <h2 id = "enter">Send Email</h2>
    </div>
</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){
        $("#emailoff").attr("href", "mailto: email@email.com
                                    ?subject=Your thinoptics glasses 
                                    body=To get your new thinoptics glasses             simply click this link and pick the case and color you like best.  You'll get  free shipping on your order

                                        WWw.Thinoptics.Com/email@email.com

                                        Enjoy")
            });
```

UPDATE:

The error is within: "mailto: email@email.com..."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't have line breaks inside the javascript string, that results in an unterminated literal and thus in the error you are getting. For readability, use:

```
"mailto: email@email.com" +
"?subject=Your thinoptics glasses " +
"body=To get your new thinoptics glasses"
```

or similar.

EDIT: If you need a line break, use `\n` inside the string.

Comment: THANK YOU! Stupid of me to do that!